# Select one email address per user

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to select one email address per user based on the following rule.
If preferred_email is Y, select that email address (email2@gmail.com).
If preferred_email is not Y, use that email address.
Some users may only have a preferred_email value of N.
I have tried using a case statement, but it didn't return the correct result.

This is an example of the table.

```
user_id email_address       preferred_email
25      email1@gmail.com    N
25      email2@gmail.com    Y
26      email3@gmail.com    N
27      email4@gmail.com    N
```

Comment: So, what is the desired output? email2@gmail.com for all 3 user_ids? Or email2@gmail.com just for user_id #25 and then email3@gmail.com and email4@gmail.com for #26 and #27 respectively?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Different versions come with different tools that can be used for top-n (greatest-n-per-group) questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX( email_address ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY preferred_email DESC, ROWNUM )
         AS email_address
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY user_id
```

or

```
SELECT user_id,
       email_address
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id
                             ORDER BY preferred_email DESC, ROWNUM )
           AS rn
  FROM   your_table t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Comment: You don't need `ROWNUM` in the `ORDER BY` clause in either solution; if there is at least one preferred email address, an essentially random one among those will be selected (with or without `ROWNUM` in the `ORDER BY` clause), and if not, an essentially random address from all of them will be selected. `max(email_address)` is pretty much the same as random in this context.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, this can be done easily with the `match_recognize` clause, like this:

```
select user_id, email_address
from   inputs
match_recognize (
  partition by user_id
  order by preferred_email desc nulls last
  all rows per match
  pattern ( ^x )
  define x as 0 = 0
)
;
```

However, this solution (as well as some of the others proposed here) has a potential weakness: it relies on the explicit ordering of `'Y'` vs `'N'`, and it assumes these are the only values possible in the `preferred_email` column (and also that the column is not nullable).

It would be better, if the column `preferred_email` is not constrained to non nullable and only possible values `'Y'` and `'N'`, to have an order clause like

```
 order by case preferred_email when 'Y' then 0 end [...]
```

Unfortunately, the `match_recognize` clause can only order by columns, not by expressions. (Hoping this will be addressed in the future!) In that case, an aggregate solution using the FIRST/LAST aggregate function, as in MT0's answer, is the best choice - but with the ORDER BY clause changed accordingly.

```
select   user_id, 
         max(email_address) keep (dense_rank first 
                 order by case preferred_email when 'Y' then 0 end) as email_address
from     inputs
group by user_id
;
```